# MongoDB get values from array in model

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is the document structure:

```js
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("547366945785c02a7c993aaa"),
   "RECNUM":"6310",
   "ART_NR":"6385",
   "ART_NRA":"11207604",
   "ART_BEZ":{  
      "fr":"Coffret cadeau"
   },
   "BES1":{  
      "fr":"Service a fondue"
   },
   "markings":[  
      "CH-TP2",
      "CH-WZ1",
      "",
      "EU-PAD002",
      "",
      ""
   ]
}
```

I need to get all the values from the markings array matching the regex:

```
'/^EU-/i'
```

for a given _id. So in this case something in return like:

```
{"markings": ["EU-PAD002"]}
```

I have no idea how to make this kind of query as I'm completly new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to achieve what you want.

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    // Filter only those documents that at least have one match
    {"$match": {markings:/^EU-/i}}, 
    // De-normalize the markings array
    {"$unwind": "$markings"}, 
    // Filter all documents that match the reg exp
    {"$match": {markings:/^EU-/i}}, 
    // Re-construct the array
    {"$group": {_id:"$_id", markings:{$push:"$markings"}}}
])
```

Output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("547366945785c02a7c993aaa"),
                        "markings" : [
                                "EU-PAD002"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

**Note:** You can add another `$project` phase to the aggregation pipeline if you dont want the _id in your result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only `markings` you can use `$projection` or use `aggregate`

projection

```
db.coll.find({markings:{$regex:/^EU/ , $options:'i'}},{_id:0,markings:1})
```

aggregate

```
db.coll.aggregate([
{
  $match:{markings:/^EU-/i}
},{
    $unwind:"$markings"
},{
      $match:{markings:/^EU-/i}
},{
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        markings:{$push:"$markings"}
    }
},{
    $project:{
        _id:0,
        markings:1
  }        
}    
])
```

result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "markings" : [ 
                "EU-PAD002"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Find stuff about $regex http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ and aggregation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Your query will return the entire document and not just the matching array elements.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan Sorry, I didn't understand!